# Linux makefile to check required minimum linux kernel version

Tags: linux, makefile

I have a linux makefile that needs to compile on 2 different kernel versions. The makefile is not generated from automake/autoconf.

The C code are already conditioned using macros to generate different code for different kernel version, but certain features in the makefile needs to be also conditioned.

Is there a way in a makefile to do:

```
if (kernel_version > 2.6.30)
    newer_kernel = 1
else
    newer_kernel = 0
endif
```

Answer (score 2):

Well, I can think of one quick way to do it with bash:

```
KERNEL_VERSION=`uname -r`
HIGHER_VERSION=`echo -e "$KERNEL_VERSION\n2.6.30" | sort -g -t '.' | tail --lines=1`
if [ "$HIGHER_VERSION" == "2.6.30" ]
   # its an older kernel
else
  # its a newer kernel
fi
```

Basically, you use uname to obtain the version of the current kernel, then compare it to 2.6.30 using `sort` (the -g flag enables numeric sorting, `-t '.'` means use dot as a field separator), then use tail to determine which of the two version was higher in the list. Not exactly a beautiful solution, but it will work.

You can put it into a separate script or directly into the makefile recipe

Comment: Beware ! ``sort -g -t '.'`` doesn't sort correctly "3.5, 3.8, 3.12" as it'll think '3.12' < '3.8'. Hopefully ``sort -V`` will work as expected.